# Change what jQuery consider an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling, promise

I'm working on a client-side app that makes call to a backend to gather some information mostly using `$.ajax`. Recently, in front of the backend, they added a proxy (to which I have no access) that changes all HTTP status codes to `200` and add an HTTP header like `ORIGINAL_HTTP_STATUS_ERROR=500` when there is an error.

All my frontend code was working before with good error handling, but since this change it obviously stopped working correctly and it's not able to handle errors anymore.

I have tried everything I could regarding ajaxSetup, overriding the success method, etc but nothing really worked. This is a big app and `$.ajax().success`, `$.ajax().error`, `$.when().fail`, `$.when().done`, etc are used from many different places, so I need an unique place to handle this. In the end, what I'm trying to do is change the logic that jQuery uses to consider something an error.
[This](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L705) is how jQuery detect if a response is successful or not:

```
function done( status, nativeStatusText, responses, headers ) {
            ...
            // Determine if successful
            isSuccess = status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304;
            // If successful, handle type chaining
            if ( isSuccess ) 
            ...
```

The only way I see to make this is to override that declared function, for what I would basically need to override (copy-paste really) the whole $.ajax method.

Is there any other way to tell jQuery what to consider an error?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `responseText` returned with `header` at error ?

Comment: Hi @guest271314. No, but I could handle that by having different default messages for different error codes. That wouldn't be a problem. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `if (jqxhr.responseText.length === 0) {// handle error }` ?

Comment: Hi @guest271314. From where? I mean, implementing the logic to detect errors would be easy, I could just check for the ORIGINAL_HTTP_STATUS_ERROR header. The problem is that the only place I can think to place that logic is inside $.ajax function done() implementation itself, what would imply changing some core jQuery code.

Comment: If interpret Question correctly, could try `.then(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {if (jqxhr.responseText.length === 0) {// handle error }})` , throw error `.then(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {if (jqxhr.responseText.length === 0) {// handle error throw new Error()}})` or `$.ajaxSetup({success:function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {if (jqxhr.responseText.length === 0) {// handle error }})` ?